# R Transposing row values to colum

Tags: r, statistics, transpose

The output of `data %>% select(Year, Type) %>% table()` give me:

```
Year  Type Freq
2001    A     5
2002    A     2
2003    A     9
...    ...  ...
2001    B    21   
2002    B    22
2003    B    19
```

How I would like my data:

```
Year  A   B   C   D   E  
2001  5  21   ..  ..  ..
2002  2  22   ..  ..  .. 
2003  9  19   ..  ..  ..
...
```

How can I achieve this? The examples I find don't seem to match my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Year",
  timevar = "Type"
)
```

gives

```
  Year Freq.A Freq.B
1 2001      5     21
2 2002      2     22
3 2003      9     19
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
dcast(setDT(df), Year ~ Type)
```

gives

```
   Year A  B
1: 2001 5 21
2: 2002 2 22
3: 2003 9 19
```

---

A `dplyr` option

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = Freq)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   Year     A     B
  <int> <int> <int>
1  2001     5    21
2  2002     2    22
3  2003     9    19
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L
), Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), Freq = c(5L, 2L, 9L,
21L, 22L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (for the quick reply)!!!

I went with `dcast(setDT(df), Year ~ Type)`

Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

An option with `base R` using `xtabs`

```
xtabs(Freq ~ Year + Type, df)
```

Comment: Your solution works, however it's a table then. Converting it to a dataframe reverses the process

Comment: @DavidBrouwer Sure, ThomasIsCoding solution is better.  There is a way to convert though.  `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Freq ~ Year + Type, df))`